# Issue rendering pdf on VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, blob.topdf

I am not able to render pdf files of size greater than 1.5 Mb on VF using the below article. Only blank screen appears on load/preview opposite to successful pdf generation  in case of <1.5 Mb pdf files

Code used is exactly the same as mentioned in the article. 
Link to SF article :
[Blob to pdf link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000044612&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

In one of the salesforce docs it is mentioned that "The maximum response size when creating a PDF must be below 15 MB before being rendered as a PDF. This is the standard limit for all Visual force requests"  however I am not sure if it is related to my issue or not.

Anyone having any idea as to why this is happening.

Comment: do you see anything in the debug logs?

Comment: No, even the blob when printed in UI is getting printed.No error in console as well.